# Principais diferenças entre MongoDB e Redis

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis

Estou a ler um livro sobre aplicações real time com NodeJs.

O autor utilizou MongoDB e Redis para exemplificar o uso de base de dados com NodeJs.

A minha dúvida surgiu quando ele utilizou as duas ao mesmo tempo, justificando que Redis seria usado para dados que necessitam de constantes actualizações porque é mais rápido a gravar e ler dados em um disco rígido.

A dúvida é, porque utilizar MongoDB? Qual a razão técnica para dividir o projecto entre MongoDB e Redis?

Answer (score 12):

Redis usa um paradigma diferente do MongoDB.

**Redis** utiliza o paradigma *chave-valor* para o armazenamento de dados. Basicamente, é um "array gigante" que fica na memória do servidor, você pede para o Redis "me dê os dados da chave XXX" e ele só retorna os dados. Ele pode trabalhar com dados simples e com listas de dados. 
**Vantagens:** o acesso aos dados é realizado de forma ágil, *sem acesso ao disco*, de [forma assinstótica](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grande-O) O(1) (traduzindo: muito rápido mesmo). 
**Desvantagens:** ele não permite operações especiais, como joins do SQL ou aninhamento de dados, sem falar que como os dados são todos armazenados na memória RAM, você precisa de espaço de memória disponível do mesmo tamanho da quantidade de dados que você vai armazenar, o que pode ser um problema.

**MongoDB** utiliza o paradigma de *documentos*. Ele armazena os dados em formato [JSON](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON), de forma aninhada (documentos podem conter dados, arrays ou outros documentos) e não relacional.
**Vantagens:** acesso rápido aos dados e fácil visualização por se tratar de um JSON, que é muito mais *human-readable* que outros formatos de dados. 
**Desvantagem:** assim como o Redis, não existe relacionamento de dados. Se for necessário algum relacionamento, ele deve ser realizado a nível de aplicação, por exemplo: Usuário B foi criado por Usuário A, mas Usuário A foi apagado do sistema, então cabe a sua aplicação tratar esse tipo de referenciamento nulo, já que o MongoDB não faz relacionamentos.

**Resumindo:** Redis é um array que fica na memória e é mais utilizado para coisas simples que precisam ser *cacheadas* ou para acesso rápido. MongoDB é um banco de dados de documentos flexível que não utiliza relacionamentos entre eles e permite que documentos guardem dados, arrays e até mesmo outros documentos.